# Ansible: How to convert a dictionary (indeterminate number of key:value pairs) to a string?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2

In an Ansible playbook, how can I filter a dictionary with an indeterminate number of key:value pairs to turn into a string, which I can then use as a command string with the Ansible shell module for example?

Sample playbook below illustrates the data, the problem, and desired result.

```
---

- name: Convert a dictionary into a string containing the key value pairs to run as a shell command

  hosts:
    - all

  vars:
    devices:
      - parameter_key: foo_device
        parameter_a: value1
        parameter_b: value2
        parameter_c: value3
      - parameter_key: bar_device
        parameter_a: value4
        parameter_b: value5
        parameter_d: value6
        parameter_e: value7

      # or like this
      - foo_device:
          parameter_a: value1
          parameter_b: value2
          parameter_c: value3
      
      - bar_device:
          parameter_a: value4
          parameter_b: value5
          parameter_d: value6
          parameter_e: value7
      
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        # I have no idea what to do here
      loop: devices

# desired result is a string, or array or strings I can then feed to the ansible shell module for execution on the host

      command_str1: "{{ foo_cmd foo_device --parameter_a value1 --parameter_b value2 --parameter_c value3 }}"

      command_str2: "{{ foo_cmd bar_device --parameter_a value4 --parameter_b value5 --parameter_d value6 --parameter_e value7 }}"

# and so on if there was more devices
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on `dict2item` filter within a loop. So you can iterate over a dict and use `item.key` to get the key of a dict and then use `dict[item.key]` to get the value. All that within a set_fact and you would have your string.

I think, there is no easier way.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    devices:
      - parameter_key: foo_device
        parameter_a: value1
        parameter_b: value2
        parameter_c: value3
      - parameter_key: bar_device
        parameter_a: value4
        parameter_b: value5
        parameter_d: value6
        parameter_e: value7
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: "task.yml"
      loop: "{{ devices }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: device
```

And the included task.yml contains:

```
---
- set_fact:
    cmd: "my_command"

- set_fact:
    cmd: "{{ cmd }} {{ item.value }}"
  when: "item.key == 'parameter_key'"
  loop: "{{ device | default({}) | dict2items }}"

- set_fact:
    cmd: "{{ cmd }} --{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
  when: "item.key != 'parameter_key'"
  loop: "{{ device | default({}) | dict2items }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ cmd }}"
```

The output would be:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: my_command foo_device --parameter_a value1 --parameter_b value2 --parameter_c value3


ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: my_command bar_device --parameter_a value4 --parameter_b value5 --parameter_d value6 --parameter_e value7
```

Comment: The provided values in the vars is a list, not a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer @TRW. I didn't think of looping an external task.yml in the main playbook.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "command is: {{ item.key }} with value of --parameter_b {{ item.value.parameter_b }}"
      loop: "{{ devices[2] | dict2items }}"
```

Gives

```yaml
    "msg": "command is: foo_device with value of --parameter_b value2"
```

Note that the values in the variables is placed as a list. It would be more convient if that is converted to an actual dictionary.